# Flight departed from the gate 5 min before scheduled departure time. Refund options

Tags: usa, airlines, compensation, missed-flights, alaska-airlines

This was Alaska Airlines flight from SJC to LAX. We ran later than we usually do on our way to flights and so we ended up reaching the gate 2 min before the scheduled departure time.

On our way from the security check to the gate we didn't hear any call for our names asking us to make it to the gate asap. (Not that we were loitering around. We were running to the gate which was at the end of that terminal.)

So anyhow, we reached there 2 min prior but were advised that the flight already left and the gate was closed. We bought a ticket from SFO and continued with the rest of our trip because there was no point arguing as the flight had already left. We were very upset and I am looking into what can be done. A few things that I am not sure of here:

1. Flights can leave ahead of time (but that is if all passengers have already boarded or there is a clear indication of no-show in that the gate is advised that some passengers didn't even checkin at the airport AND they have approval by the ATC of course). We did checkin and so we shouldn't have been marked no-show.
2. Departure time is time to leave the gate and not take-off. Confirm this.
3. How could I prove the airline left minutes ago? Could I ask the airlines for the record of the flight on that particular day?
4. If I do prove this, can we ask for any sort of compensation?

Any other advice (other than "don't go that late"). As I said, it doesn't always happen but when it happens we should know our options.

Comment: The scheduled departure time is usually intended to be the time the aircraft _physically starts moving_ away from the gate/stand. The boarding bridge general needs to be retracted at least several minutes before that, doors closed and secured, etc.

Comment: And if the aircraft is parked at a remote stand, it can quite easily be that the apron bus needs to leave the terminal building ten minutes or more before the scheduled departure time.

Comment: I’m struggling to understand why you would think you have any options in this scenario. It’s not as if ‘be at the gate by x minutes before the scheduled time’ is a recently-invented approach

Comment: @Traveller - there is nothing to struggle to understand if you accept that the question was asked because of a lack of knowledge. If 'be at the gate x minutes...' is not new, so aren't late arrivals. In fact, I have seen experiences when flights have waited for passengers (connections & first flight alike). Often, flights say to arrive 3 hours in advance at the airport but not everyone does it. Even with boarding, it starts roughly 30 min prior but your boarding may not be until your group is called. So you could show up even after your group boarded.
The below ans was valid and it is upvoted

Comment: Why were you "late" to the gate?  Were you just late getting to the airport or were you on a connecting flight that was late getting there so you had to run to try and catch the next leg an missed it?

Comment: @perennial_noob I wasn’t suggesting the question is invalid. You appear to have flown before (“we ran later than we usually do on our way to flights”) and there’s nothing in your question about any extenuating circumstances causing you to run late. I was therefore just intrigued to understand why you’d think any compensation might be due or any other redress might be available to you apart from the tax/fees refund mentioned in Aganju’s excellent answer

Comment: *"Departure time is time to leave the gate and not take-off. Confirm this."* Suppose the listed departure time was the flight's allocated take-off slot time. That would be utterly useless to almost every passenger on any given flight, as they would have no idea of such things as for how long the aircraft needs to taxi to get to the runway. Confused travellers do not benefit the airline, and since (to within experimental error) the airline wants passengers to travel with them again, it stands to reason that the airline would try to make the process of travelling as hassle-free as possible.

Comment: @aCVn: To be fair, the current practice of quoting block-off times is not all that much of an improvement over takeoff times. In an ideal world the published departure times would be "join the check-in line at this time at the latest and we'll get you to point B" times, namely the point where the passenger's own travel arrangements stop mattering and everything starts depending on capacity allocations that the airline (or their providers, such as the airport) controls. But there doesn't seem a reasonable way to get to that ideal world from the one we have.

Comment: @Traveller: The OP is asking about options. The question doesn't read to me as "I expect a full refund, how do i get it?" but as "What are my options?". For example in your comment you say "apart from the tax/fees refund mentioned in Aganju’s excellent answer" - given that isn't anywhere in the question surely that is *exactly* the sort of information that the OP is after. I am struggling to understand why you think the question should be about more than the obvious...

Comment: @Chris We seem to have interpreted the question differently. I guess for me the idea that compensation might be due to someone who arrived at the gate 2 minutes before the scheduled departure time seemed bizarre.

Comment: @Traveller: I agree that it seems bizarre but given there *is* compensation in form of being able to reclaim taxes/fees it seems that it was worth asking. And even if there wasn't having a question whose answer is "no, you can't get anything" is still completely valid to me.

Comment: What you can claim fundamentally depends on the fare you paid for, which you haven't given any details on. It varies wildly: If you paid for a full-fare unrestricted ticket, you're entitled to go on any flight to the destination, no matter who's fault it was. If you bought a high-level refundable ticket, you're entitled all your money back, again regardless of fault. A mid-priced ticket is typically a new flight with a ~$50 penalty, which can be waived if the gate agent feels nice. A highly discounted ticket = out of luck.

Answer (score 83, accepted):

If you check your ticket, it will say something like '*all passenger must be at the gate and ready to board x minutes before the scheduled time, or they forfeit their flight*'.
I have seen times required between x=10 and x=60 minutes, but never less than 10 minutes. In other words, if you miss this limit, it's your own problem, and they don't owe you anything.
For Alaska Air, it is here: https://www.alaskaair.com/content/travel-info/at-the-airport/airport-boarding-times

> **Boarding:**
>
> You must be checked in with a valid boarding pass at the gate
> no later than 30 minutes before your flight. Being late may cause the
> cancellation of your reserved seats and/or your entire reservation.

You typically can apply for a refund of the tax and fee part of the ticket price, as they haven't paid those taxes/fees if you are not on the flight, but the remaining part of the ticket might be lost (as are all follow-up legs of the flight), depending on the airlines conditions.

If you ask at the counter right away and nicely, many airlines will get you on the next flight, for a small fee or even for free. But they do *not* owe you that.

Comment: I'm curious - do you know how this might apply to connecting flights? I once narrowly avoided this same scenario, however I was late due to my incoming flight taxiing for an extended period, not for simply arriving at the airport late.

Comment: @That1Guy Depends. If you were traveling on two separate tickets/reservations, it's your own problem. If you had a single reservation for both flights, the airline is responsible for making sure you catch your connection, or offer you an alternative.

Comment: @J.Hougaard That makes sense. My case was the latter - I had a single reservation, so its good to know the responsibility falls on the airline in those cases. Thanks for the info!

Comment: Airlines in the US don't generally refund taxes and fees on non-refundable tickets. I'm not sure of Alaska's policy, and you can ask them, but it's not typical for US airlines to do this. It is much more common in Europe.

Comment: If this is your case, and you bought your ticket with a credit card, you might check if your CC can help at all.

Answer (score 19):

> So anyhow, we reached there 2 min prior but were advised that the flight already left and the gate was closed.

Say the flight "departure time" is 10:40:00

You simply can't arrive very close to that time.  You have to arrive before the ***"gate closes"***.

That's that.

The time the gate closes is indeed **given on the boarding pass stub**, and elsewhere in many places.

It's usually ten, twenty or thirty minutes before the stated departure time.  Perhaps 10:20:00 in the example.

Regarding your four questions:

1) You checked in, but, did not make it to the gate before the gate closed. This is totally commonplace. (Indeed, I'd guess that most folks who don't make it to the gate in time, were already checked in.)

2) "Departure time" is neither literally the time the aircraft leaves the gate nor take-off time.  So there's nothing to "confirm". "Departure time" is a nominal time.  {Note too that FWIW, the airbridge moving away, doors being locked etc, are all different from literally "the wheels beginning to roll".}  The gate closes at a certain time (10:20 in the example) and that's that.  Everything after that simply depends on airport operations.

3) You can get that info on the various tracking sites, eg flightaware.com. But it's totally irrelevant because (sorry for the bad luck) you did not make it to the gate by the "time the gate closes".

---

(Interestingly, I've noticed that many/most boarding passes now only display the gate closing time, rather than displaying the "departure time".  I guess this is sensible but I find it confusing, personally!)

Comment: I wish airlines would list a time that I had to be at the airport _entrance_ for - instead of needing to make assumptions about how long check-in, TSA/security, and getting to the gate takes. This would be useful for airports I'm not familiar with. As much as missing one's flight sucks, it isn't much help when you waste 2-3 hours because you're too early.

Comment: @Dai Airlines can't really do that because it varies dramatically even at the same airport for reasons that the airline often won't know in advance. Most airlines do have a time by which you must check in for the flight, though, especially if you're checking baggage. This is typically at least half an hour prior to departure. I've seen as much as 1.5 hours, especially for international airlines that may only have one service from that airport on a particular day and, thus, shut down the check-in counters once they're finished with that flight.

Comment: "The time the gate closes is indeed given on the boarding pass stub, and elsewhere in many places." This is airline-specific. Some do, some don't. It's less common in the U.S. However, all of them will at least tell you "you must be at the gate ready to board by at least X minutes prior to the scheduled departure time."

Answer (score 5):

I ran into this problem twice about 15 years ago with American Airlines – first time at the gate 10 minutes before scheduled departure, the second 15 minutes before, and each time already gone. Both times they rebooked me for later flights, but weren't apologetic about it. Second time, it completely messed up my itinerary (I needed to connect with someone else arriving at the destination about the same time, for further travel by car to somewhere I didn't have the address for, and everyone else involved had unlisted numbers. Disaster.) Oh well.

Several years later I was very interested when The New York Times wrote a story about the fact that this had become official policy of AA, and that it had finally become enough of a PR black eye (as social media grew in prominence) for them to stop it. But what was interesting was why they did it in the first place - because they found in focus groups/surveys that:

- travelers glanced at their watches as they pulled back from the gate, and this moment anchored their future impression/recollections of whether the airline was efficient and timely;
- travelers assigned blame for delays **to the airline** if they left the gate late;
- but not if the airline was delayed out on the tarmac, waiting for clearance to takeoff – then they blamed **the airport**, or just **rotten luck**.

So it made sense to game their impressions by always leaving early, and if the occasional traveler was inconvenienced, too bad.

Comment: That's is the official policy of pretty much every airline: the departure time is the time the flight is scheduled to depart, and you're expected to be at the gate at least a certain time before that. It is true that [American has been particularly focused on getting flights out on time in recent years](https://www.thestreet.com/story/14057376/1/american-airlines-leaves-thousands-of-passengers-at-gates-as-it-pushes-on-time-departures.html), and has left standby passengers behind as a result.

Comment: Note that in many cases “the flight as already left” actually means “the gate has already closed”. The aircraft may have not moved yet, especially if it’s at a remote stand.

Answer (score 0):

Most boarding passes will have two times printed, the boarding time, and the departure time.  Boarding time is typically 45 minutes before the departure time.

Boarding is usually open for 15 minutes starting at the boarding time.  If you do not get to the gate within 15 minutes of the boarding time, you are counted as a no-show.

In Heathrow, you have to be there a full hour before your flight's departure time, or else the security gates will not even let you enter the secure zone of the airport.  This happened to me once.  Got stuck in London traffic, arrived during the fifteen minute boarding time, but the service counter for the airline had already closed, and the security gate scans the boarding pass to let you in.  It would not accept my boarding pass.  The airline counted it as a "no-show" so I had to buy another ticket.